# How to remove wordpress top menu bar?

Tags: wordpress

How to remove this wordpress top bar ?

[image]

I am doing it by css, is it right ?

```
#wpadminbar {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with PHP, add this to your functions.php file

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

Although ideally this should be done in a child theme as will be undone when the theme is updated.

I don't think there is anything wrong with doing it the way you are already doing it with CSS though.

Comment: Thanks its worked, I will consider your suggestion about child theme.